# Read in 2D array

Tags: arrays, matlab, file, file-io

I'd like to read in the following format from a file into a 2D array:

```
      -1.2545186e-01   6.1235522e-01
      -3.3039316e+00  -5.7215697e+00
      -4.3039316e+00  -7.7215697e+00
```

Is there any (builtin-) function to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`importdata`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html):

```
x = importdata('file.txt');
```